# How can I examine the query string generated by Spring Data Cassandra Mapper

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

If I annotate a class with annotations from `com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations`, I can write a test along the lines of:

```
MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
Mapper<MyAnnotatedClass> mapper = manager.mapper(MyAnnotatedClass.class);

MyAnnotatedClass entity = ...;

RegularStatement saveQuery = (RegularStatement) mapper.saveQuery(entity);

assertEquals("...", saveQuery.getQueryString());
```

However I have entity classes annotated with `org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping` annotations. I've been unable to find an Spring equivalent to `Mapper`'s `saveQuery()`, `getQuery()` and `deleteQuery()`.

How can I write (ideally lightweight at runtime) tests regarding the CQL generated from Spring Data Cassandra-annotated entity classes?

Comment: There's no test support to verify statements derived from Spring Data Cassandra-annotated entity classes. What's your motivation behind query string testing?

Comment: @mp911de I want a test-driven way to gauge cause-and-effect when working on the annotations. One might argue that only cause-and-effect in terms of what ends up in the tables matters, but right now I feel I'd prefer something more contract-y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.5, you can write the following code to create `Statement`s:

```
CassandraTemplate template = …

Person person = …

CqlIdentifier tableName = template.getTableName(Person.class);

Insert insert = CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery(tableName.toCql(), person, 
                    new WriteOptions(), template.getConverter());

Delete delete = CassandraTemplate.createDeleteQuery(tableName.toCql(), person,
                    new WriteOptions(), template.getConverter());

Update update = CassandraTemplate.createUpdateQuery(tableName.toCql(), person, 
                    new WriteOptions(), template.getConverter());
```

Note: Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.5 uses `BATCH` statements for inserts, that's going to change with the release 2.0.

`CassandraTemplate` and `CassandraConverter` are the key classes involved in query creation for version 1.5. In Spring Data 2.0, things are going to change a bit as 2.0 is going to ship with additional `Query` and `Update` types for partial entity updates. So query creation moves from `CassandraTemplate.create…Query(…)`to `QueryUtils.create…Query(…)`.

Comment: This works like a charm - thanks. Is there anything similar for `SELECT`?

Comment: No, because in 1.5 you're required to pass in a `Select` or a select using plain CQL. You can dive deeper to create `WHERE` predicates based on entity type and id (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/6b683f4346c6476f3c80e56e6bcd0df5b3eed4bc/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraTemplate.java#L179-L182) but that's quite cumbersome.